# Sort a table by a column that has multiple repeating ID names

Tags: r, dplyr, datatable, tidyr

I am trying to sort a table that I converted from wide to long using the tidyr and dplyr packages.

```r
data_long <- gather(data_wide, family, abundance, Phietavirus:Phi29virus, factor_key = TRUE )
```

This is how part of the resulting table looks like [data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCRgT.png)

The ID's, will be repeated for each type of virus. In total there is 10 type of viruses. I am trying to sort the table by the ID number. I have tried the following code but it gives me an error.

> data_long<- data_long[order(data_long$`ID`)]
> Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
> x Locations 5, 16, 27, 38, 49, etc. don't exist.
> ℹ There are only 3 columns.

I think the problem might be the repeating ID's, but I am not sure. In order for me to move on with the graph plotting, I need to sort the long table first. If anyone could help figure out how to sort this, it will be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO, would you please use `dput(head(data_long))` and add the result to the answer. People will most likely need to look at the data in order to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's going wrong with your code (unless you don't actually have a column called exactly `ID`), but you could try using `arrange()`:

```
library(dplyr)
data_long <- data_long %>% arrange(ID)
```

Also, I think you might be missing a comma before the `]` which would leave the result with no columns (and error).

Comment: Thanks Elle! The script that I was trying to follow had it using order, but it never worked.  But just tried what you suggested and it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear it!